# How to enforce a strict class schema in ES6

Tags: javascript, schema, ecmascript-6

I am new to es6 and am wondering if this approach is OK.I do not want someone to set properties that I do not want on my object.

```
export default class User {

static getMembers() {
    return ['username','email','fullname','birthdate'];
}

constructor(props) {
    Object.keys(props).forEach((p)=>{
        if (User.getMembers().includes(p)) this[p]=props[p]
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this,"username",{writable:false});
    Object.defineProperty(this,"email",{writable:false});
}
```

any other approaches?

Comment: With the above, you can't set any value for `username` or `email`. They'll always be `undefined`, as you've made them read-only and haven't assigned them a value.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I do assign them a value before the defineProperty is run through the constructor and then it becomes non writable.

Comment: Well, only if they're on `props`...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That seems to be the expected usage. I don't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Although responses were exactly what I asked for, I think I didn't phrase the question very well. I was looking if there is a pattern in Javascript for objects to behave more like statically typed OOP languages that you cannot add members other than those the class creator wanted.  Object seal doesnt let us add new properties but I would like to add one if it is in the "allowed" list. should I make a new question for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your code as shown, you can't set any value for `username` or `email`. They'll always be `undefined`, as you've made them read-only and haven't assigned them a value. You also haven't done anything to prevent code with access to one of these objects setting a completely arbitrary property:

```
let u = new User();
x.anythingIWant = 42;
```

If you want to prevent code from adding properties to an object, you can do that with `Object.seal` (ref: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal), [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.seal)), which prevents new properties being added and makes it impossible to re-define existing properties. So:

```
export default class User {
    constructor() {
        // ...create your desired properties

        // Seal the object
        Object.seal(this);
    }
}
```

And if you also want to make `username` and `email` read-only, you'd also include the `Object.defineProperty` calls you have (*before* the `Object.seal`). Just make sure you assign them values first, as once you've done that `defineProperty` and `Object.seal`, you can't change them anymore.

I think I'd probably approach using that array of whitelisted properties slightly differently as well, by just looping through the array.

So:

```
export default class User {
    static getMembers() {
        return ['username','email','fullname','birthdate'];
    }

    constructor(props) {
        // Create the properties
        User.getMembers().forEach((name) => { this[name] = props[name]; });

        // Make sure username and email have a value, because we won't
        // be able to change it in a moment
        // ...

        // Make username and email read-only
        Object.defineProperty(this, "username", {writeable: false});
        Object.defineProperty(this, "email", {writeable: false});

        // Seal the object
        Object.seal(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: but making sure that I only set properties that I want in the constructor is it ok to use a static array of properties like that?

Comment: @arisalexis: If you like, sure. I think I'd probably do it differently, though: `["username", "email", ...].forEach((name) => { this[name] = props[name]; })`. No need for the method that returns the array (though it's harmless), or for using `includes`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: `User.getMembers()` is overwritable though, while that array literal is not so easy to access.

Comment: @Bergi: Indeed -- which could go either way. :-) (Thanks for the fix.)